# How to add the head from one repo on top of the existing head?

Tags: git

I have two repositories repo1 and repo2 where repo2 at some point was cloned from repo1. Now I need to replace the master branch from repo2 with the master branch from repo1. I want to keep the history in repo2 intact and just add whatever is in the master branch of repo1 as a commit to repo2.

So it's gonna be something like this:

Repo2

```
                     D------E-----F (branch to keep)
                    /
init----A----B----C------G-----Head(h2) (master)
```

Repo1

```
init----A----B-....-Z-----Head(h1) (master)
```

---

What I want

```
                     D------E-----F (branch to keep)
                    /
init----A----B----C------G-----h2----HEAD(h1) (master)
```

after this operation the master branch in both repositories should be identical.

Is this the right way to do it? (I cannot risk trying it first then realise it's wrong!!)

1. git clone repo2.git repo2 && cd $_
2. git remote add upstream repo1.git
3. git fetch upstream
4. git rebase upstream/master
5. git push origin master --force

Answer (score 1):

First off, even though you show "h1" in both repos when you're done, realize that the commit IDs will be different...

I feel like the easiest way to accomplish what you're asking would be to checkout master in both repos, then just copy the files from repo1 into repo2. Then commit it to master on repo2.

That being said, this seems like an odd thing to do. I wonder why you want to maintain the history of master in repo2 if you want the file system to not actually reflect any of those changes? Once you "replace" master in repo2 with that from repo1, you are undoing any of the changes that you wish to track the history for. Also, with different IDs for the same files, you're repos are always going to be out of sync. I wonder if you'd simply be better off reverting the changes on master, then merging back into master, then syncing up the two repos with the merge commit in place. This way your history is still maintained and both repos are the same, in case you want to do this again in the future.

Comment: That's true that the SHAs will be different for sure, I just wanted to visually indicate they are basically the same snapshot. 
Regarding the history, I think anything else would make going back in the history just more complicated. This way I have the history of both repos (repo1 which will become inactive and repo2).
And the copy/paste the changes and simply committing it actually doesn't seem that bad (+1) (This is a Terraform repository so not many files). Not sure if this is the best way tho.

Comment: @mok OK. Since you want the files from repo1, it seems like it would make sense to keep the history of the commits that got you there too, but it seems like you want to throw that history away and keep the history of repo2 instead, even though you are essentially undoing those changes. :)

Comment: I understand what you say regarding the history and agree with it, but I'm not sure if wiping the history for master it wouldn't impact the other branch that I must keep (including it's history) in repo2. That's why I don't want to mess with it.